# where does phpcs store values on windows os

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer, phpcs

I am able to do successfully the command

```
phpcs --config-set show_progress 1
```

but I don't know where phpcs stores this values on my disk on Windows 7 Operating System.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Phar file, it will be in a file called CodeSniffer.conf in the same directory as your Phar file.

If you have installed via PEAR, it will be at PHP_CodeSniffer/CodeSniffer.conf inside your PEAR data directory (run `pear config-show` and look for the data_dir line to find where that is).

If you have installed via Composer, it will be at vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/CodeSniffer.conf

If you have cloned from Git, it will be in a file called CodeSniffer.conf inside the cloned PHP_CodeSniffer directory.